# Express.js pass variable from function to view

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, global-variables

I need to pass some arrays created from a previous function to the next one, in order to send them to the client. Now I use public variables in order to achieve my goal, but I know this isn't a good practice and there's probably a better way to do what I'm looking for. Here's my code:

```
var myArray; // public array
app.use('/users', findUsers, someOtherFunctions, function(req, res){
  res.send('users.ejs', {
  array: myArray,
  (etc...)
})})

function findUsers(req, res, next){
  db.find({}, function(err, array){
  if(err) throw err;
  if(array.length > 0){
    myArray = array
  }
  })
  next();
}
```

Is there another way to do it, without creating public variables? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If `myArray` is supposed to contain something specific to this particular request (and it does look like it), you might wanna use `res.locals`, see the reference for details: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals.

**UPDATE:**

So, with `res.locals` your example would look somewhat like this:

```
app.use('/users', findUsers, someOtherFunctions, function(req, res) {
  res.send('users.ejs', {
    array: res.locals.myArray,
    (etc...)
  });
});

function findUsers(req, res, next) {
  db.find({}, function(err, array) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (array.length > 0) {
      res.locals.myArray = array
    }

    next();
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to use it? The docs aren't that clear! Thank you!